# Continuous function cuts y=x line

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions

Well this might be very trivial or just an application of a theorem unknown to me -

If $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ be two points on the curve of a continuous function such that

$a>b $ and $c<d$

Show that there's a point $(g,g)$ on the curve. It looks so natural yet I can't prove it rigorously.

**PS**:I am not sure if the tags are appropriate. I'd appreciate if you can help me with that .

Comment: Extremely sorry ! Edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: Let $f$ denote your function and define $g$ by $g(x) := f(x) - x$. What can you say about the signs of $g(a)$ and $g(c)$?

Comment: you mean g(a) and g(c)...

Comment: @8pir Right, thanks.